# Determine target framework and version from release build folder

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I have been tasked with creating a "service installer" console app in .net core, that will query a remote file server for available apps to install on a given server. There will be a master known directory to look in for directories with various app names. Within each app-name directory will be directories named with the app-name and semantic version number. In these directories will be the release version compiled .dlls and the various other files that Visual Studio 2017 places there. IE; .net core apps all seem to have a .deps.json file with a "runtimeTarget" object containing a "name" property that I could query for the version. However, a regular .net framework app doesn't have this file, it has just the .config in xml format with supportedRuntime and sku. And if it's just a class library, nothing but the .dll and .pdb, neither of which are query-able in this scenario... One of the requirements is to verify compatibility with the current environment before "installing"... Any ideas?

Comment: May have an answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46897911/how-can-i-find-the-platform-a-net-assembly-has-been-compiled-against-programmat

Comment: Nope. This would work from inside an app, but this is not applicable to my situation where I want to query from outside. Back to the original idea of a flat file in the repository that maintains a list of app-versions and the targeted framework-version.